# Windows batch file to rename output file with files I am compressing.

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I am compressing a file and trying to rename my output file, by ways of reading the original file and renaming the output file with the original filename. Currently I am running a batch file that will compress a file by creating the shell in the archive directory and copying the file into it. Also I am creating a log file for the event. I'm using 7-Zip command-line version to do the compression.

```
echo Start Compression

7za a -t7z "c:\Archive_Directory\%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%-%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~-4,4%.7z"  "C:\File_To_Compress\*.xls" >"C:\Users\Compression_Logs\_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%-%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~-4,4%.log"

echo Finish Compression    

timeout /t 30
```

The batch file creates/compresses the necessary files and gives all files the same name because of the timestamp. Just wish I can figure out how all files can have the original filename.

Example Output of what I have:
Original Filename - Source.xls
Compressed file   - 1030-05012017.7z
Log File                - 1030-05012017.log

What I want: 
Compressed File - Source_1030-05012017.7z
Log File               - Source_1030-05012017.log

Comment: `HELP FOR` will provide some useful information, especially as regards parameter expansion. Your attention is directed to the `%~` expansions, and specifically `%~n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo Start Compression

for %%a in ("C:\File_To_Compress\*.xls") do set "name=%%~na"

7za a -t7z "c:\Archive_Directory\%name%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%-%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~-4,4%.7z"  "C:\File_To_Compress\*.xls" >"C:\Users\Compression_Logs\%name%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%-%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~-4,4%.log"

echo Finish Compression    

timeout /t 30
```

Set `%%a` to the name of each file matching the mask in turn then assin each in turn to `name` (`%%~na` means `name part only`)

Use `name` as a string in the filenames required.

Note: it is regarded as more usable to show timestamps as YYYYMMDDHHMMSS which allows alphabetical sorting in a logical manner.

```
echo Start Compression

for %%a in ("C:\File_To_Compress\*.xls") do (

 7za a -t7z "c:\Archive_Directory\%%~na_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%-%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~-4,4%.7z"  "%%a" >"C:\Users\Compression_Logs\%%~na_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%-%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~-4,4%.log"
)

echo Finish Compression    

timeout /t 30
```

This version will individually create archive and log files for each source file

Comment: As written, this will not work; it will only give the name of the last file in the expansion. See [the FOR command at ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) for grouping multiple commands using `(` and `)` within the `FOR` command.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - I'm guessing that was a deliberate choice for some reason.

Comment: @SomethingDark: Seemed OP wanted to compress all target files to one single file - so what name to assign? If each was to be compressed individually, why? - an xls file is relatively small to start with, so there doesn't appear much point.

Comment: @Magoo - I don't disagree with the evaluation of the utility of compressing Excel workbooks; I could, however, see this as a CMVE for a generalized "archiving" procedure, and commented from that point of view.